# d3 zoom on scroll does not work anymore on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js

Probably there was a recent Chrome update which brake d3 zoom on scroll feature. Everything still works perfectly fine with e.g. Edge. Please check this simple example for a proof - http://bl.ocks.org/nnattawat/9689303

Maybe anyone knows how we can revert to an older Chrome version to get this feature working again?

Comment: It seems like the scroll button is unregistered after page load. For a brief second you are able to zoom. 

I am having the same issue. The commit I think broke the zoom is https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/974d38f7d850b8ea2052f3c76fe2381a0b72f0b5

The d3 zoom functionality seems to work just fine for d3.v4 and over

Comment: not sure about the last affected version of d3. I am using 5.14.2 and still can reproduce the issue

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think Chrome was updated and the issue is gone. Closing the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have also been running into this "bug" also - see this [github thread about it](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/231)

In most of the examples that I've seen where it is no longer working in Chrome 89.0.4389.90 (Windows) anymore, the zoom is being attached to the non-root SVG element.

As in the [d3-zoom observable example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoom), make sure it is the root SVG is the element that `d3.zoom()` is called on, not a `<g>` or `<rect>`:

```
const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

  const g = svg.append("g");

  g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .join("circle")
      .attr("cx", ([x]) => x)
      .attr("cy", ([, y]) => y)
      .attr("r", 1.5);

  svg.call(d3.zoom()
      .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .scaleExtent([1, 8])
      .on("zoom", zoomed));

  function zoomed({transform}) {
    g.attr("transform", transform);
  }

  return svg.node();
```

Comment: I hope this is an unintended change from the Chrome team, I've reported this as an issue. Attaching zoom handlers to rects is a good way of divvying up complex zoom behaviours, something we do in our application quite heavily.

Comment: @Sawri I have sent the report to Google as well. No answer received yet

Comment: Calling it on the `svg` element does seem to work in general. However in my use case I don't think I can do that. I'm attaching to a child `rect` which is then destroyed when I want to disable the zooming (unless there is a better way to achieve this...)

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue on Chrome in our CMS.
Installed the https://www.smoothscroll.net/win/?extension
The issue is gone.

Or check out this from the same author:
https://github.com/gblazex/smoothscroll-for-websites

Comment: Yep. The Chrome extension helps with this bug in Chrome 89.0.4389.90

Answer (score 1):

As temporary fix you can run this on page load:

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', () => {})
```